# org.apache.lucene.analysis.StandardAnalyzer cannot be resolved

Tags: java, apache, maven, lucene

When implementing **tokenization** by using Lucene a problem related to `org.apache.lucene.analysis.StandardAnalyzer` occurred as the following exception was thrown:

> The import org.apache.lucene.analysis.StandardAnalyzer cannot be resolved

I added dependencies to Maven pom.xml (see below) but the same exception was thrown again.

I used those dependencies:

```
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers-common</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-queryparser</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-queries</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-test-framework</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.lucene</groupId>
        <artifactId>lucene-analyzers</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use version 3.6.2?

Comment: @user1071777 I removed 3.6.2 but got the same exception again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `lucene-analyzers` dependency.

You can't mix-and-match package versions with lucene, and the `lucene-analyzers` package is no longer used.  You already have the dependency to `lucene-analyzers-common`, which is what you should be using.

Also, you need to import `org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer`, instead of `org.apache.lucene.analysis.StandardAnalyzer`.

Comment: I removed `lucene-analyzers` dependency but got the same exception again.

Comment: @RaufAgayev Ah, missed the mistake in the import before.  It should be `org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer`.

Comment: One additional note:  There was some pretty significant restructuring of packages, and changes to functionality in Lucene 4.0, particularly.  If you are looking at code or documentation or anything like that from before 4.0, bear in mind that it will most likely not work using the latest versions.  Luckily, it's usually not too difficult to update the code.